# Como enviar objetos para função

Tags: php

Estou começando com PHP POO e estou tentando passar uma classe para uma função.

Como posso fazer isso?

```
$usuario = new Usuario();
registraUsuario(Usuario $usuario,$conexao);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa usar o tipo para passar um parâmetro

```
registraUsuario($usuario, $conexao);
```